# multi conditions for sort function javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to sort by BOTH day and order.

Condition 1: sort by day (1-7)

Condition 2: sort by order (1-5)

It must sort day first and then order.

I can easily sort by day using sort function. 
I can't sort together same time.

Data to sort

```
[
 {id: 1,
  day: 4,
  order: 2      
 },
 {id: 2,
  day: 2,
  order: 1,
 },
 {id: 3,
  day: 1,
  order: 5
 },
 {id: 4,
  day: 5,
  order: 5,
 } 
]
```

Result I expect:

```
[
 {id: 3,
  day: 1,
  order: 5
 },
 {id: 2,
  day: 2,
  order: 1,
 },
 {id: 1,
  day: 4,
  order: 2      
 },
 {id: 4,
  day: 5,
  order: 5,
 } 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.day - b.day || a.order - b.order);
```

```js
let arr = [
 {id: 1,
  day: 4,
  order: 2      
 },
 {id: 2,
  day: 2,
  order: 1,
 },
 {id: 3,
  day: 1,
  order: 5
 },
 {id: 4,
  day: 5,
  order: 5,
 } 
]
arr.sort((a, b) => a.day - b.day || a.order - b.order);

console.log(arr);
```